# Sending data via SPI / Atmega 8

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I have a few question about SPI in AVR (atmega 8).
I'd like to transmit byte 0xfe , 
but function looks like this :

```
void sendDataSpi(char data )
```

Does it mean that I have to convert my intiger (hex value ) into char and then send
or can I send directly hex like below :

```
 sendDataSpi(0xfe);
```

Should it works ?
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up representation and identity of a value.

So you don't send hex if you send `0xFE`.

The conversion from `0xFE` and `-2` or `254` happens in the compiler. They are the same thing as far as we see here (depending on if `char` is signed or unsigned on your platform).

So yes, of course, it will work the way you do it.

Comment: nevertheless is `void sendDataSpi(char data )` a poor API. since data (raw byte) should be transfered also the data type should reflect this. the interface should be `void sendDataSpi(uint8_t data)`. `char` is for character data.